# How to understand the geography of Napoleon's military campaigns?

Tags: historiography, napoleon

I am currently reading Napoleon The Great by Andrew Roberts and I am facing a few issues. While I can understand when Roberts describes Napoleon's life, I am having a hard time understanding the military campaigns of the book.

He mentions places like Lodi & Toulon but it is hard to even visualize and understand what is happening because I don't even where those places are or how they look, or what some of the artillery names mean, as well names of people. Andrew Roberts includes a map but I had a hard time using it.

Has anyone else faced this issue? How did you overcome it?

Comment: Tracking military movements is an acquired skill.  I'll admit it significantly undermines my enjoyment of military history.  Good question.

Comment: @Rushil - you might find these history videos helpful. Probably over-simplified, but lots of interactive maps showing the various theatres, of war.  https://youtu.be/91OmO2YMiDM

Comment: "Has anyone else faced this issue? How did you overcome it?" Yes, every person reading history books faces this problem: the authors/editors rarely include good maps (this would rise the production cost of the book significantly). Nowadays we have Internet, and good maps can sometimes be found. Concerning  other things (special terminology, names etc.), Wikipedia is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[West Point Military Atlases](https://www.westpoint.edu/academics/academic-departments/history/atlases) has an entire volume devoted to [The Napoleonic Wars](https://www.westpoint.edu/academics/academic-departments/history/napoleonic-wars).

Here are two samples:

- **[Italian Campaign - Seizing Central Position, 10 - 14 April, 1796](https://www.westpoint.edu/sites/default/files/inline-images/academics/academic_departments/history/Napoleonic%20wars/Nap02.pdf):**
  [image: Italian Campaign - Seizing Central Position, 10 - 14 April, 1796e]
- **[Central Europe, 1809 - Danube Campaigns, Situation 15 April 1809 and  Deployment of Opposing Forces](https://www.westpoint.edu/sites/default/files/inline-images/academics/academic_departments/history/Napoleonic%20wars/Nap39.pdf):**
  [image: Central Europe, 1809 - Danube Campaigns, Situation 15 April 1809 and Deployment of Opposing Forces]